# How to install a msi in PlayOnLinux script?

Tags: windows-installer, wine

I'm writing a PlayOnLinux script to install a program, called GHC, that have an installer in the form of a Windows Installer (.msi file).

I've tried to run it with:

```
POL_Wine "$INSTALER"
```

But this give me the following error:

```
02/24/16 14:05:18 - [POL_Wine] Message: Running wine- /home/jabellota/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/GHCTempFiles/GHC18.msi (Working directory : /home/jabellota/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts)
02/24/16 14:05:18 - [POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
wine: Formato EXE erróneo en Z:\home\jabellota\.PlayOnLinux\tmp\GHCTempFiles\GHC18.msi.
```

I found that to install msi with wine (in a normal shell) you must execute it as bellow or it didn't recognize the msi:

```
wine msiexec /i GHC18.msi
```

I tried also to do a:

```
POL_Wine "msiexec /i $INSTALER"
```

But wine try to execute the program "msiexec" and didn't found it.

¿How can I install a msi in a script of PlayOnLinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the answer in [the forum by MTres19](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-13806-How_to_install_a_msi.html).*

You can use:

```
POL_AutoWine "$INSTALLER"
```

which just calls msiexec.exe for MSIs. Or you can use:

```
POL_Wine msiexec /i $INSTALLER
```

I think the quote marks mess up flags with programs, so you just have to get rid of them or maybe put them outside of the quote marks. There's not much point in not using POL_AutoWine anyway unless you need the script to be asynchronous (that is, the script doesn't pause while Wine is running.) like this:

```
POL_Wine start msiexec /i $INSTALLER
```